# How do I read the systemd MemoryHigh value from the /sys/fs/cgroup filesystem?

Tags: systemd, cgroups

I have a systemd service that sets `MemoryHigh` and `MemoryMax`. If I look under its cgroup in `/sys/fs/cgroup/memory` the `memory.limit_in_bytes` file matches the limit set by `MemoryMax`, but where do I find the value set by `MemoryHigh`? There is a file named `memory.soft_limit_in_bytes` so I expected it to be that, but its value is always 9223372036854771712 (8 EB?).

The [doc for MemoryHigh](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html) says

> This controls the "memory.high" control group attribute

but there is no file with that name.

This is on Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The resource control documentation also mentions that

> `MemoryLow=` and `MemoryHigh=` are effective only on unified hierarchy.

“Unified hierarchy” means [cgroup v2](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cgroup-v2.txt) *only*; you’re using v1 or hybrid mode. To use unified hierarchy, if it’s not the default, the system should be booted with [the `systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy` option](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.html#systemd.unified_cgroup_hierarchy).