# Working with systemd unit file override, can it have multiple sections of the same name like [service]

Tags: linux, systemd, systemd-unit

I am interested in trying to override the CPU utilisation of a systemd service. So that I don't lockup the machine on some CPU heavey process that I run periodically.

After running `systemctl edit containerd.service`
I see that there are two `[Service]` sections.

For example:

```
systemctl cat containerd.service
# /lib/systemd/system/containerd.service
[Unit]
Description=containerd container runtime
Documentation=https://containerd.io
After=network.target

[Service]
ExecStartPre=-/sbin/modprobe overlay
ExecStart=/usr/bin/containerd

Delegate=yes
KillMode=process
# Having non-zero Limit*s causes performance problems due to accounting overhead
# in the kernel. We recommend using cgroups to do container-local accounting.
LimitNPROC=infinity
LimitCORE=infinity
LimitNOFILE=infinity
# Comment TasksMax if your systemd version does not supports it.
# Only systemd 226 and above support this version.
TasksMax=infinity

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target

# /etc/systemd/system/containerd.service.d/override.conf

# https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/494843/how-to-limit-a-systemd-service-to-play-nice-with-the-cpu
# https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.resource-control.html
[Service]
CPUAccounting=True
CPUQuota=95%
MemoryAccounting=True
MemorySwapMax=0
```

When I look at the specific values

```
systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl show containerd.service | grep MemorySwap
MemorySwapMax=infinity
```

They don't show up as having changed. 
Am I misunderstanding how all this is supposed to work.

When I look at a different value it does show up as changed. Previously `CPUAccounting=` was empty

```
systemctl show containerd.service | grep CPUAccountin
CPUAccounting=yes
```

Further info

```
systemctl --version
systemd 237
+PAM +AUDIT +SELINUX +IMA +APPARMOR +SMACK +SYSVINIT +UTMP +LIBCRYPTSETUP +GCRYPT +GNUTLS +ACL +XZ +LZ4 +SECCOMP +BLKID +ELFUTILS +KMOD -IDN2 +IDN -PCRE2 default-hierarchy=hybrid


uname -a
Linux srv-acquisitions02 4.15.0-66-generic #75-Ubuntu SMP Tue Oct 1 05:24:09 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Comment: Do you have a unified control group hierarchy?

Comment: @StephenKitt, My immediate answer is I don't know. Which probably means No. 
I will RTM on this.

Comment: Sorry, I should have given some pointers; see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/498837/86440) for a start.